# How to add more user data to URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to add more user data to the URL. Currently, I am trying to add the $last_name string into my function, but I cant seem to get it right.
In the future, we might add more info into the URL depending on the user registering.

Please check the code below:

P.S. I got the base of the function here on Stackoverflow, however not sure which link. I have made changes to the function to suit my needs.

It is successful in pulling the first name.

```
function add_userid_page_url(){
    
    $user_info = get_userdata(get_current_user_id());
    $first_name = $user_info->first_name;
    $last_name = $user_info->last_name;
    
    if( is_user_logged_in() && is_page('my-account') && !isset( $_GET['fname'] ) ) : //Check User Logged In and Account Page and User Info not set in URL
        wp_safe_redirect( add_query_arg('fname', $first_name, get_permalink() ) );
    endif; //Endif
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'add_userid_page_url');
```

Comment: What have you done so far to try and debug this? Have you verified the function gets called in the context you want it to? Have you checked that all of the individual conditions of the `if` statement yield true?

Comment: I have tried adding another $_GET to the string various ways ( ,$_GET && $_GET "" && $_GET) and nothing. However, I am able to somehow call lname into the URL, but not the $last_name.

Not sure what you mean really on the if statement yield true

Answer (score 1):

Just an update.

I figured out a way to add userinfo into URL structure.

For incase anyone needs it in future

```
    <?php
      function add_userid_page_url(){
      $user_id = get_current_user_id();
      $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
        $logged_in = array (
          $first_name = $user_info->user_firstname,
          $last_name = $user_info->user_lastname,
          $email_address = $user_info->user_email,
        );
      if( is_user_logged_in() && is_page('my-account') && !isset( $_GET['user_details'] ) ) : //Check User Logged In and Page and User Id not set in URL
         wp_safe_redirect( add_query_arg( 'user_details', $logged_in, get_permalink() ) );
      endif; //Endif
        }
      add_action('template_redirect', 'add_userid_page_url');
    ?>
```